# React MUI 5 DatePicker with react-final-form not handling keyboard input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-final-form

I want to first make clear that this question is about the recently-released MUI 5 DatePicker, i.e. from `@mui/x-date-pickers`. I previously used the `KeyboardDatePicker` in the older versions of material-ui with no issues and have taken a similar approach here to integrate the DatePicker with react-final-form.

I have my DatePicker:

```
function DateInput(props: any) {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker
        {...props}
        renderInput={(params: any) => {
          return <TextField {...params} />;
        }}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

I wrap this in a react-final-form `Field`:

```
function DateFormField({
  name,
  label,
  inputFormat
}: {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  inputFormat: string;
}) {
  return (
    <Field name={name} parse={(value) => formatDateTime(value)} type="date">
      {({ input, meta: { touched, invalid, error } }) => (
        <DateInput
          {...input}
          label={label}
          inputFormat={inputFormat}
        />
      )}
    </Field>
  );
}
```

and I place it into a react-final-form `Form`:

```
<Form initialValues={formInitialValues} onSubmit={handleSubmitClick}>
  {({ handleSubmit }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <DateFormField
        name="asOfDate"
        label="As Of Date"
        inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
      />
      <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </form>
  )}
</Form>
```

The issue is when trying to type full dates into the DatePicker using the keyboard. My Field receives the correct date, the TextField inside the DatePicker receives the correct date, but the Material UI control itself will display the wrong date. If I set the initial value to something like `new Date("0002-07-28")`, the DatePicker will display "07/27/2002" (not even 7/28/2002, weirdly enough). This is mainly an issue when you try to type over the year portion of a date (or backspace the in the year portion of the DatePicker to try and retype the year), it tries to push you to the 21st century. If I delete the year portion, I should be able to type e.g. "2021", but on the first keypress of the "2", the DatePicker displays "2002." How can I modify the control to allow input into the year portion of the DatePicker?

I created a working sandbox demonstrating my issue here: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui5-react-final-form-datepicker-9wvtnp?file=/src/Demo.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not going to be a satisfying answer because I don't know why my approach was wrong, but I got it to work by using the  `render` prop instead of `children` prop:

```
<Field
    name={name}
    validate={getFieldValidator(validators)}
    render={(fieldRenderProps) => (
        <DatePickerInput
            label={label}
            inputFormat={format}
            {...fieldRenderProps}
        />
    )}
/>
```

and modifying the `DateInput` object a tiny bit:

```
function DateInput(props: any) {
  const {
    input: {
        name, onChange, value
    }
} = props;
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker
        name={name}
        onChange={onChange}
        value={(value as any) === '' ? null : value}
        {...props}
        renderInput={(params: any) => {
          return <TextField {...params} />;
        }}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

See [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui5-react-final-form-datepicker-forked-bll9er?file=/src/Demo.tsx) for a working CodeSandbox.

Answer (score -1):

First of, when you are trying to set the initial date to the year 2, this component will not work, for it can only go back to the year 1900.

Secondly, you need is a bit of state to store your date for when it changes and a function to handle those changes, that you pass to the component. Here's how that would look in your case:

```
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Field } from "react-final-form";
import { Typography, Button, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { AdapterDateFns } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns";
import { DatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
import { format } from "date-fns";

function DateInput(props: any) {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker
        {...props}
        renderInput={(params: any) => {
          return <TextField {...params} />;
        }}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}

export const formatDateTime = (input: any) => {
  if (!input || (input instanceof Date && Number.isNaN(input.getTime())))
    return "";
  if (typeof input === "string") {
    return input;
  }
  return format(input, "MM/dd/yyyy");
};

function DateFormField({
  name,
  label,
  inputFormat,
  value,
  handleChange
}: {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  inputFormat: string;
  value: Date | null;
  handleChange: (value: Date) => void;
}) {
  return (
    <Field name={name} parse={(value) => formatDateTime(value)} type="date">
      {({ input, meta: { touched, invalid, error } }) => (
        <DateInput
          {...input}
          label={label}
          inputFormat={inputFormat}
          value={value}
          error={touched && invalid}
          helperText={touched && error}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      )}
    </Field>
  );
}

export default function Demo() {
  const [dateValue, setDateValue] = React.useState<Date>(
    new Date("07/28/1902")
  );

  const handleSubmitClick = () => {
    alert(format(dateValue, "MM/dd/yyyy"));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Typography variant="h6" component="div">
        Demo Form
      </Typography>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmitClick}>
        {({ handleSubmit }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <DateFormField
              name="asOfDate"
              label="As Of Date"
              inputFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"
              value={dateValue}
              handleChange={(value) => setDateValue(value)}
            />
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </form>
        )}
      </Form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Or interactively: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui5-react-final-form-datepicker-forked-78f13f?file=/src/Demo.tsx

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am still working through this (and typing a date now works), but my main issue with this answer is that I can no longer set the default/initial value of the form field by using the [Form's initialValues prop](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/types/FormProps#initialvalues). I created an MVP for the purpose of this question, but typically I have a Form with a large number of fields, and I use `initialValues` to set all those values. In the above example, the DateFormField value won't get set. Any ideas?

Comment: Digging into this further, your `handleSubmitClick` is just displaying your local React state variable, `dateValue`. If I try to alert on the form values itself (when you submit a form, it should pass the form values), the form values are empty, so this is NOT a workable solution. The DatePicker control works, but the Form does not.

Comment: You can solve both issues easily. For the initialValue, this can be passed into the useState hook. If for some reason you cannot access the value when useState is called you can set it using useEffect. For the form values being in state vs the form itself,  you can use controller components. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: I'm aware of what controlled components are. I am building reusable form controls, and keeping states in two places (using `useState` and the react-final-form) defeats the purpose. Yes, I can pass an initialValue to the useState, but then react-final-form's `form.reset()` won't control it, and would need to write separate logic every time I wanted a date field in my form. Following your train of logic, I wouldn't need a form at all, I would maintain state on my own, which defeats the purpose of using a <`Form>`.

Comment: reaact-final-form also uses state, and you can use that state for you datepicker. See: https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/examples/react for an example. Good luck!